# Multiply values from 2 json files

Tags: json, multiplication

I'll start working on a website but I need some help with a Json code. I just need to extract a line from this json code:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json

Exactly this line:

```html
},
    "USD": {
        "transferencia": 984.13,
```

Well, I just need to multiply that number by the current exchange rate between USD and CAD (0,71532 at this moment). Finally, I just want to show the final result (in this case: 703.84) in a wordpress or a joomla site. The hardest part is those numbers are changing over time and I don`t want to it manually everyday. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just grab that code by dotwalking it out of the JSON object. Then you could store the value into a variable or other data structure and run a scheduled job to say if the value changes, run your multiplication function and deliver the result.